# HighCharts Drill down not working

Tags: highcharts

I have created a HighCharts bar chart and now I want it to drill down in to further detail.

Here is my [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AnandVishnu/3ECdP/)

My data looks like this

```
var seriesData =  [{
                name: 'A',
                data: [
                    { 
                        y : 10, 
                        drilldown: {
                        name: 'A',
                        categories: ['1', '2'],
                        data: [5, 7],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                    }, 
                    { 
                        y : -29, 
                          drilldown: {
                        name: 'A',
                        categories: [' 1', '2'],
                        data: [5, 7],
                        color: colors[0]
                    }
                    }
                ]
            }];
```

I am still not able to drill down in to detail view

Answer (score 0):

Just start with this example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

This is proper setting for drilldown:

```
            series: [{
                name: 'Brands',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: data
            }],
            drilldown: {
                series: drilldownSeries
            }
```

In your data `drilldown` is full series, while should be just series ID from `drilldown.series`. Study for a while example from above URL, it's really simple example.